# Create index on field from parent class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have problem with adding index. I use hibernate with annotation driven configuration.

I have something like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String profileId;
   ...
   //getters and setters
}
```

and several child classes

```
@Table(name="note")
public abstract class Note extends BaseEntity{
    //different fields
}
@Table(name="message")
public abstract class Message extends BaseEntity{
    //different fields
}
```

I want to add index to field "profileId" in class BaseEntity. But if I do so, with annotation @Index(name="profileid_index"), it creates only for table "note", and fails on "message", because index "profileid_index" already exist.

I did not find way, how to make hibernate generate unique index names. Or may be someone knows another solution how to index field in parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look on @Tables annotation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/ ?

You can do stuff like:

```
@Tables(value={@Table(appliesTo="table1", indexes={@Index(name="index1", columnNames={"column1", "column2"})}),  
           @Table(appliesTo="table2", indexes={@Index(name="index1", columnNames={"column1", "column2"})})})
```

Should help in your case if you put this annotation to your @MappedSuperclass, although I don't know if there is a more cleaner solution

Being more precise, you could try for your case:

```
@Tables(value={@Table(appliesTo="note", indexes={@Index(name="index_profile_id1", columnNames={"profileId"})}),  
           @Table(appliesTo="message", indexes={@Index(name="index_profile_id2", columnNames={"profileId"})})})
```